# Show image when div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a big image when I click on the smal image witch is in a div. 
I've try this with jQuery but it doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#imgVieuw').hide();

    $('.click').click(function(){
        var element = $(this).attr('id');
        var element2 = element;
        element = "#" + element2;
        var bigimg = "#v" + element2;
        $('#vincent, element').click(function() {
            console.log(element+" "+bigimg);
            $('#imgVieuw, bigimg').fadeIn();
        });
    });

    $('#closeButton').click(function() {
        $('#imgVieuw, .img').fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>

<section id="vincent">
    <div class='click' id="img1"><img src="images/vincent/tumb city.png"></div>
    <div class='click' id="img2"><img src="images/vincent/tumb city2.png"></div>
    <div class='click' id="img3"><img src="images/vincent/tumb eye.png"></div>
    <div class='click' id="img4"><img src="images/vincent/tumb island.png"></div>
    <div class='click' id="img5"><img src="images/vincent/tumb planet.png"></div>
    <div class='click' id="img6"><img src="images/vincent/tumb tiger.png"></div>
    <div class='click' id="img7"><img src="images/vincent/tumb white tiger.png"></div>
</section>
<div id="imgVieuw">
    <img class="img" id="vimg1" src="images/vincent/city.jpg">
    <img class="img" id="vimg2" src="images/vincent/city2.jpg">
    <img class="img" id="vimg3" src="images/vincent/eye.jpg">
    <img class="img" id="vimg4" src="images/vincent/island.jpg">
    <img class="img" id="vimg5" src="images/vincent/planet.jpg">
    <img class="img" id="vimg6" src="images/vincent/tiger.jpg">
    <img class="img" id="vimg7" src="images/vincent/white tiger.jpg">
</div>
```

You can look for an example at my demo webpage, and click on the button vincent: [http://vwdemo.comxa.com/parallax](http://vwdemo.comxa.com/parallax/)
There you find my thumbnails.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code significantly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('.click').click(function () {
         var bigimg = '#v' + this.id;
         $('#imgVieuw').find(bigimg).fadeIn();
     });

     $('#closeButton').click(function () {
         $('#imgVieuw .img').fadeOut();
     });
 });
```

Note that `$('#imgVieuw, bigimg')` makes no sense, as it should be something like  `$('#imgVieuw').find(bigimg).fadeIn();`

Also you should never bind click events inside other click event handlers, this way you end up with bunch of handlers bound to the same element.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w0mzhL8a/